# Passing an attribute in Jquery/javascript didnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $(function () {
        $(".itemsTable").on("click", "#addClaimItem", function() {
            debugger;
            var tableName = $(".itemsTable").attr('name').toString();
            PopulateTable(tableName, null, null);    //tableName = "CorrectValue"
        });
    });

    function PopulateTable(tableName, baggageItems, isuneditableInEnquiryMode) {
       var table = $("#" + tableName + " table");  //tableName = null
        debugger;
        var id = table.attr("data-id");
...code continues

<div id="BagList">
    <div class="fieldBox">
        <div class="field">
            <table data-id="@(Model.Trav.BagPage.BagList.Count())" class="itemsTable" name="BagList">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Receipt</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                        <th>Present Value</th>
                        <th>Amount Claimed</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trav.BagPage.BagList.Count(); i++)
            {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].BagDescription, new {@class = "tableData-input editableInNew editableInUpdate itemDescription", @readonly = ""})</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].BagAge, new {@class = "tableData-input editableInNew editableInUpdate age", @readonly = ""})</td>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].BagReceipt, new {@class = "tableData-input editableInNew editableInUpdate receipt", @readonly = ""})</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].BagCost, new {@class = "tableData-input editableInNew editableInUpdate currencyAmount", @readonly = ""})</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].BagPresentValue, new {@class = "tableData-input editableInNew editableInUpdate currencyAmount", @readonly = ""})</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].BagAmountClaimed, new {@class = "tableData-input editableInNew editableInUpdate currencyAmount", @readonly = "" })</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="removeClaimItem minus editableInNewSymbol editableInUpdateSymbol disabled">
                                    @Html.Hidden(Html.NameFor(x => x.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].MarkedAsDeleted).ToString(), Model.Trav.BagPage.BagList[i].MarkedAsDeleted.ToString().ToLower())
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
            }
                    <tr class="plusRow">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="addClaimItem" class="plus editableInNewSymbol editableInUpdateSymbol disabled"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the tableName variable null within the function itself?  I cant find an anwser to this anywhere( I must be a bit of a noob) Have tried a few variations but stumped!

Edit: In Chrome Element Inspector the javascript/Jquery values are given see values given //tableName = *value*.  var tableName is initially set to "bagItems" but when PopulateTable function receives tableName it is set to null????????
There is no id in the table tag but there is also an id="BagList" further up the ancestors of the table

Comment: Are `name` and `id` identical?

Comment: Is it `tableName` which is null or `$("#" + tableName + " table")` returns empty matched set?

Comment: This is unclear, jQuery's `attr` generally does not return null, but an empty string if the attribute does not exist, and `toString` does not return null unless called on null. What does the HTML look like ?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/bfk8aoru/1/) - assuming you only have [one element of that class](http://jsfiddle.net/682r5nud/4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andy got it right, thank you very much!
I will put more code up next time as the question was unintentionally confusing, Sorry!

```
$(function () {
    $(".itemsTable").on("click", "#addClaimItem", function () {
        debugger;
        var tableName = $(this).closest(".itemsTable").attr('name').toString();  //This helped also
        PopulateTable(tableName, "blah", "blah");
    });
```

The above $(this).closest(...  also prevented issues